# Enxergar e ver! Qual é a diferença?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Acabei de descobrir que **enxergar** tem o mesmo sentido como **ver**.

É sempre assim?

Por exemplo:

> Espero que agora você *enxergue* melhor com esses óculos.

> Espero que agora você *veja* melhor com esses óculos.

Tem o mesmo sentido?

Comment: Tentaste consultar um dicionário, Majid? Com que dúvidas ficaste?

Comment: Sim, são até que bem diferentes. Para não teres que esperar a resposta de alguém, recomendo veres um dicionário, como disse @ANevesthinksSEisevil. Estes são os meus dicionários favoritos: Aulete (http://www.aulete.com.br/), Priberam (https://dicionario.priberam.org/) e o meu favorito, o Houssaiss (https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v5-4/html/index.php#0).

Comment: @Schilive Para acessar o Houaiss, só com assinatura do UOL, não?

Comment: @stafusa, só precisa se logar no UOL, mas não precisa de assinatura. Se precisar, eu estou pegando algo sem saber.

Comment: @Schilive Não acho página de cadastro grátis com eles, só assinatura...

Comment: @stafusa, entrando no site pela aba anónima do Google Chrome, quando pesquiso uma palavra, o site pede para se logar, mas não mostra onde criar a própria conta. Acho que é possível criá-la aqui: https://checkout.uol.com.br/#/widgetnotify/0?promotion=ZDEFCADVISITANTE&sg=2668383698&sa=uolhome&dest=https:%2F%2Fwww.uol.com.br%2F.

Comment: @Schilive Muito obrigado! Eu realmente não estava conseguindo encontrar uma maneira de me cadastrar gratuitamente. Agora consigo acessar o Houaiss.

Comment: Pode achar alguma explicação aqui -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frbFHsOtUy8

Comment: @Schilive Quando concluo o cadastro o site diz "Há erros no seu cadastro Desculpe, a página não pode ser carregada. Tente novamente." Sabes como resolver?

Comment: @William, 'tás usando que e-mail? Digo, é Gmail, por exemplo?

Comment: @Schilive Obrigado pela resposta. Sim, é gmail. Tentei novamente agora e recebi o mesmo erro.

Comment: @William, talvez já tenhas uma conta. Tenta te logar e, se não der certo, tenta pedir para recuperar a senha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em alguns casos tem o mesmo sentido.

Na maioria dos casos, você pode trocar "enxergar" por "ver". Mas o contrário pode soar estranho. Por exemplo:

> Você viu as notícias de ontem?

> Você viu ela passando?

> Com licença, tu podes ver as horas para mim?

Nas sentenças acima, se trocar por "ver" por "enxergar", não soa natural, mas não muda o sentido da sentença.

Parece-me que "enxergar" está mais relacionado com algo mais difícil de ver, que tenha algum detalhe que requer mais atenção.

Porém, quando alguém quer diferenciar entre uma visão mais superficial de uma visão mais profunda, este atribui a visão mais profunda ao termo "enxergar". No entretanto, eu não dúvido que você possa encontrar o contrário, ou seja, alguém usando o "ver" para algo mais profundo e o "enxergar" para a simples visão.

Comment: https://jornal.usp.br/radio-usp/olhos-apresentam-particularidades-entre-enxergar-e-ver/ Neste exemplo ele considera o contrário, e é interessante a resposta deste link, sendo que eu também uso da forma que coloca na sua resposta. Tanto que eu falo: "Eu vejo, mas não enxergo". Justamente para adicionar esta diferenciação nos níveis da capacidade do olhar.

Comment: Pois, ai está. Usar "ver" e "enxergar" para diferenciar essa diferença de visão não é algo definido. Além disso, acabo de ver que tanto "ver" quanto "enxergar" é traduzível para "videre" em latim, acho que isso é mais um ponto para se pensar.

Answer (score 5):

#### Técnica

Usando o Dicionário Houssaiss (https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v5-4/html/index.php#1), peguei os significados um por um do verbo *ver* para entender a diferença e semelhança entre os verbos *ver* e *enxergar*. Eu peguei cada significado dado pelo Houssaiss, então, peguei um exemplo dado pelo Houssaiss, então, troquei o verbo *ver* pelo verbo *enxergar* para ver se são sinonímias.

Os dois maiores problemas dessa técnica é que a interpretação pode variar de pessoa para pessoa, então talvez eu conclua que duas frases são semanticamente diferentes, mas outrem conclua que são iguais. O outro é que eu não tenho formação de lingüística, nem tenho conhecimento formal de semântica.

#### Resultados

Há 10, de 21, significados compartilhados entre si, sendo todos esses significados todos os significados de *enxergar*, ou seja, é sempre possível trocar *enxergar* por *ver*, mas nem sempre o contrário, assim como ensinou Matheus em sua resposta.

A principalíssima diferença é que *ver* pode significar “olhar para”. “Eu vi os desenhos” não é igual a “eu enxergo os desenhos”, mas este pode significar que o falante consegue perceber visualmente o desenho, o que também é transmissível através do verbo *ver*. Geralmente *enxergar* está mais ligado com a idéia de conseguir perceber (algo ou alguém) visualmente do que *ver*.

Outra diferença importante é que *ver* pode significar encontrar, visitar ou ter encontro com alguém ou algo, então “vejo a minha mãe aos domingos” não é igual a “enxergo minha mãe aos domingos”. *Ver* pode significar ter ciência, saber, como em “ele saiu com um estranho sem ver quem era”, inequivalente a “ele saiu com um estranho sem enxergar quem era”. O verbo *ver* também significa pesquisar, procurar, investigar ou analisar (algo ou alguém); ex.: “já vi na estante e não encontrei”.

Há outras diferenças, mas creio que essas são as principais.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, são sinônimos e tem o mesmo significado.

Na prática, existem diferenças culturais que variam com o tempo, região geográfica, classe social, etc.
Você pode ter algo como "apenas viu, mas não enxergou". Como se o enxergar fosse mais denso, detalhado. Mas é muito subjetivo e particular de cada contexto.

Na prática, significam a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, ENXERGAR e VER são sinônimos. Pelos exemplos que você colocou na pergunta, as frases são as mesmas.
Porém, há sim como montar frases com essas palavras de forma diferente, geralmente ligados de forma emocional, principalmente referindo-se a cegos.
Para eles, NÃO ENXERGAR é mais utilizado para classificar o defeito deles. Porém, a palavra VER entra no vocabulário deles como o verbo SENTIR ou NOTAR.

- Aquele cego pôde VER/NOTAR que quão simpática era aquela atendente.
- Mesmo cego, ele pode VER/SENTIR como aquela sala estava suja.

Answer (score -1):

Para o cientista Masataka Watanabe, um dos maiores estudiosos do assunto, ver e enxergar são realmente ações muito diferentes. Para ele, ver está em aprofundar sua visão sobre o objeto visto e analisá-lo mais de perto. Já enxergar é apenas olhar sem avaliar com mais cuidado aquilo que se está enxergando. Quando estamos numa livraria, por exemplo, podemos dizer que ao folhear as páginas de um livro estamos apenas enxergando suas folhas, entretanto, quando passamos a ler suas páginas, estamos realmente vendo e interagindo com o conteúdo apresentado pelo autor.

Comment: Valderi00, Masataka Watanabe é um neurocientista japonês; não é um linguista nem fala português (que eu saiba). Ele não disse nada acerca das palavras  *ver* e *enxergar*; várias publicações de língua portuguesa é que usaram estas palavras para explicar a pesquisa dele.

Comment: Procura você pesquisar mais um pouco meu querido antes de vir criticar blz abraço

Comment: Olá, Valderi00, bem-vindo ao site. Nós procuramos manter aqui um tom cordial e construtivo - se você acredita que as críticas do Jacinto não se aplicam, por favor argumente e aponte referências de suporte.